# Angular router with optional query parameters

Tags: angular, router

I have router

```
{
  path: 'reset-password',
  component: ResetPasswordComponent,
}
```

And I want to be able to open it as a direct link (`/reset-password`), or with passed parameters (`/reset-password?uid=gsSxc&code=DsdxFSd`), and so when creating a router snapshot I want to see the passed parameters.

How can I do this? Do I need to create two different routers for this?

Comment: /reset-password&uid=gsSxc&code=DsdxFS put ? after /reset-password to be /reset-password?uid=...

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat yes, but how should I define path in my router?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You dont need to have separate route since all query params are always optional and you should handle required parameters inside of your component.

Or define your required parameters in url to be  `path: 'reset-password/:uid',` and path optional parameters via query String `reset-password/1234?queryString=true`

Comment: You could also handle them in a route guard.